# Using another class's method(s) in a method

Tags: java, methods, inner-classes

UPDATE: It comes out that my problem is related to main constructor.I didn't initialize class instances properly so java pointed my problem was regarding to line where my method are.In other words, my methods were problem because they didn't initialized properly.

I have 3 classes. The 1st one sets a `Date`, the 2nd one calculates an invoice and uses 2 instances of the `Date` class. The third class uses 1 instance of the 2nd class in `main()`.

My problem is, I am trying to use the `setDates` method in the 2nd class that uses 1st class instances with their methods but it doesn't works.

Here is Java error:
      Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at InvoiceDate.setDatesFromUser(InvoiceDate.java:57)
        at Thirdclss.main(Thirdclss.java:7)

I would like suggestions on how to fix the code or another way to do the same thing so it works properly.

Here is sample code for the 3 classes. Please comment if I did not specify my problem clearly enough.

```
//first class that set date

public class OurDate {
    private int day;

    public OurDate() {
        day = 1;
    }

    public OurDate(int d ){
        day = d;
    }

    public void inputDay( ) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a day(1-31): ");
        day = keyboard.nextInt();
    }// end inputday

    public int calcTotalDay() {
        int x = ((year*365)+(month*30)+day);
        return  x;
    }
}
```

Here is the 2nd class:

```
public class InvoiceDate {
    private double invoiceAmount;
    private OurDate todayDate;
    private OurDate invoiceDate;

    public InvoiceDate (double invoiceAmount,OurDate todayDate, OurDate invoiceDate){
        this.invoiceAmount = invoiceAmount;
        this.todayDate = todayDate;
        this.invoiceDate = invoiceDate;
    }

    public void setDatesFromUser (){  //HERE is where I stuck
        todayDate.inputDay();        //inputDay is method in OurDate class
        invoiceDate.inputDay();
    }

    public void calculateInvoice(){
        int DayAmt = todayDate.calcTotalDay()  -  invoiceDate.calcTotalDay() ;
        invoiceAmount = (DayAmt/30)*5; 
    }
}
```

The third class just gets an instance from the 2nd class and main constructor.

```
 //Third Class
 public class Thirdclss  {
public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("Welcome");
    InvoiceDate invDate = new InvoiceDate(10, null, null);
    invDate.setDatesFromUser();
    invDate.calculateInvoice();

}
```

}

Comment: You need to reduce the amount of code in your question to the absolute minimum requited to show the problem, and make your question as narrow in scope as possible, so it's clear.

Comment: Shortened code as much as possible

Comment: Try adding `keyboard.next();` after `day = keyboard.nextInt();`, which will clear the line feed from the input buffer.

Comment: What error/problem are you seeing?

Comment: Make them public or inherit them by extending the class you want to borrow from.

Comment: What means *it does not work* : compile time error (message), run time error (stack trace), flames every where (call fire department), wrong values (expected and actual) ?

Comment: I am trying and combining suggestions.I wrote error that java gives.

Comment: @Serge added error that code gets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the members in `InvoiceDate`:

```
public class InvoiceDate {
    private double invoiceAmount;
    private OurDate todayDate = new OurDate();
    private OurDate invoiceDate = new OurDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how you are getting an instance of InvoiceDate in the third class, try:

```
//Third Class
public class Thirdclss  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome");
        InvoiceDate invDate = new InvoiceDate(10); //this line had the issue
        invDate.setDatesFromUser();
        invDate.calculateInvoice();
    }
}
```

Update:

In the constructor you are passing `null` for `todayDate` and `invoiceDate` remove these and change the second class:

```
public class InvoiceDate {
    private double invoiceAmount;
    OurDate todayDate = new OurDate();
    OurDate invoiceDate = new OurDate();

    public InvoiceDate (double invoiceAmount) {
        this.invoiceAmount = invoiceAmount;
    }
    //rest of class
```

Comment: I corrected instance name and its fields.Still gets null pointer error

Answer (score 0):

```
public InvoiceDate(){
    minutesPurchased = 0.00;
    todayDate = new OurDate();    //This is the how I should initialize 
    invoiceDate = new OurDate();  //instances from class 1.This is the solution...
}
```